# How to run rake jobs:work in background?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, sharetribe

I am deploying **[Sharetribe](https://github.com/sharetribe/sharetribe)** application. Following their [documentation](https://github.com/sharetribe/sharetribe), I need to run `bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production jobs:work`. The problem is that after execution of this command, I need to close the `SSH` connection, and to do this I have to exit `jobs` process.

How can I run `bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production jobs:work` in background?

Comment: Typically, you put that `bundle exec` command into an `upstart` service (or whatever supervisor is used on your system). This way, you achieve two goals: worker is started automatically on boot and it doesn't depend on your interactive session status.

Answer (score 1):

Integration of a backgroud in stain executants at startup.

To do so, we will use [systemd].

1. Create the file YourJob.service in / etc / systemd / system /. #The File will be used to define the code to execute in the background.
2. Run the command "enable systemctl YourJob.service"
3. Create a .sh script file in any such directory "/home/marketuser/bin/rakejob.sh"C
4. Checked the status of execution of YourJob.service service with the command "status systemctl tmarketjob.service"
5. reboot the server.

File structure.

## # YourJob.service

```
    [Unit]
    Description = Tmarket background processing daemon program

    [Service]
    Type = Single
    ExecStart = / home / marketuser / bin / rakejob.sh
    Restart = always

   [Install]
   WantedBy = graphical.target
```

## # Rakejob.sh

## ! / Bin / bash

```
export PATH = / home / marketuser / bin:     /home/marketuser/.nvm/versions/node/v6.1.0/bin: /home/marketuser/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin: / home / marketuser /. rbenv / shims: /home/marketuser/.rbenv/bin: / usr / local / sbin: / usr / local / bin: / usr / sbin: / usr / bin: / sbin: / bin: / usr / games: / usr / local / games
cd / var / www / tmarket /
exec rake jobs: work
```

[-] The PATH is obtenur by executing the console command 'echo $ PATH'
tmarket is the directory of our RoR application

- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-systemd-units-and-unit-files

Answer (score 0):

You can run it like any other console command by using nohup or just adding & symbol in the end of the command, but note that solution with & will be stopped if you will close the terminal tab with it.

Answer (score 0):

Please include the gem "daemons" to your Gemfile. And use the below command

RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job start

For more information please check the [delayed job gem](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job).